# Rx.js unsuscribe giving gerror

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm currently starting out with observables in JS, and I've hit a total roadblock with what seems like something really basic. I've created the super simple example below, which whilst useless by itself, looks to me like it should work, but it doesn't. the final line throws an error.

```
const obs1 = Rx.Observable.timer(2000)
    .map(() => {return Math.random() > 0.5});

const subscription = obs1.subscribe(
   (v) => {
      console.log('hello world: ', v)
   });

subscription.unsubscribe();
```

The error is

> TypeError: subscription.unsubscribe is not a function

My question is basically, why can't I unsubscribe from the above observer? Or how should I unsubscribe from it?

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: It was throwing 'Uncaught TypeError: subscription.unsubscribe is not a function'

Comment: `console.log(subscription)` would have saved you a lot of time.

Comment: Tried that, saw the method was missing, look at the docs, didn't help, tried googling the type of subscription, didn't help. So no, it didn't save me any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be using Rx v4.x, isn't it? In that case, the method is `dispose` not `unsubscribe`

```
subscription.dispose();
```

Your two options are to either:

- upgrade to rxjs v5;
- replace `unsubscribe` with `dispose`.

If you codebase hasn't mush code yet, I suggest you upgrade to v5 :)

Comment: Considering that he mention rx.js, then yea, he is using RxJs 4

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Nice catch indeed, but still not really enough to be sure :)

Comment: Yes, I am using v4. I will try updating to v5. If it works, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Updating to v5 fixed the issue. I cannot confirm if changing to dispose would have worked.

Comment: I think it is pretty safe to say that it would have fixed the issue :) Glad I could help :)

Comment: Yeah, not saying you're wrong I just didn't try it. Thank you for the help.